# SSH remote connection working "every other reboot"

Tags: ssh, reboot

Latest raspberry pi os lite installed on a raspi4 4gb, customized to my needs.

I can normally SSH into it, everyhing works.

I then reboot (sudo reboot) and raspi won't respond to SSH connection anymore, nothing at all, no connection refused message, no nothing. Normally responds to pings. I can attach monitor and keyboard and use it normally, I can even ssh to locahost when I'm physically using it and everything is fine.

I then either reboot with attached keyboard, or cold reboot by unplugging the power, and at the next reboot SSH works normally again.

Rinse and repeat.

I tried both systemctl status ssh and journalctl -e -u ssh.service, nothing out of the ordinary, I do see a "connection closed by [my laptop ip] on port [somerandomport][preauth]" when I closed putty client out of desperation, nothing more.

Tried restarting SSH service while this was happening, changed nothing, I still need to reboot the damn thing for SSH to work again. I'm considering to trigger a single reboot on crotab @reboot and check that it won't go on loop via a static file...

Comment: Are you certain it has actually rebooted?  It's possible something fails as its stopping services and it aborts the reboot, leaving the pi in a 1/2 stopped state.  `uptime` should help determine if this is the case, or `last`

Comment: Yup, certain: after issuing sudo reboot in the remote ssh shell, the display connected to the pi shows a successful shutdown and restart cycle

Comment: Do you have both wifi and ethernet setup?  Is it possible one is configured statically?  I've seen cases where the static network was disconnected and the routing table randomly would default to the disconnected network.

Comment: I was going to say no right away, but instead I checked, and surely enough iwconfig reports no wifi extensions, so I remembered correctly that I had wifi disabled. Still, a solid lead :)

Comment: For clarification, is it timing out or just hanging?

Comment: It appears to be hanging, I don't get any error on putty's side

Comment: I haven't used putty in a long time, is there an equivalent option of `-vvv` for verbose debugging?  If you can enable that, edit the question and paste the output there.